# Updating an exiting excel sheet using epplus giving error

Tags: c#

I want to update an existing `.xlsx` file using Epplus. I have Open Office installed on my system. I want to open `Sample.xlsx`, which is also created by Epplus for the first time and if the file already exists, then it updates it. I am using the below code for updating the file, but I'm getting

> General Input/Output error

when trying to open file using `Process.start("...")`

```
ExcelPackage l_ExcelPackg = null; 
ExcelWorksheet l_ExcelSheet = null;
//Update existing file 
FileInfo l_FileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\\Files\\Sample.xlsx");
l_ExcelPackg = new ExcelPackage(l_FileInfo);
ExcelWorkbook l_WorkBook = l_ExcelPackg.Workbook;
//Get 10th sheet of excel to update
//1 to 9 sheets keep unchanged

l_ExcelSheet = l_WorkBook.Worksheets[10];
l_ExcelSheet.Cells.Clear();

//First row having column names
foreach (DataColumn l_dcColumn in p_dtSelectedRows.Columns)
{
    l_ExcelSheet.Cells[1, l_intColums].Value = 
    p_dtSelectedRows.Columns[l_dcColumn.ColumnName].ToString();
    l_ExcelSheet.Cells[1, l_intColums].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    l_intColums++;
}

byte[] l_byteArr = l_ExcelPackg.GetAsByteArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(p_strFilePath, l_byteArr); 

ProcessStartInfo l_objProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(p_strFilePath);
Process.Start(l_objProcess);
l_ExcelPackg.Dispose();
```

Please suggest what changes are required in code?

Comment: What are the contents of `p_strFilePath`? You should also be able to simply go to Start|Run (or whatever it is now in Windows) and paste that string into the box, and have it open up. Does that work? Note that prior to that, you have the filename *hardcoded*, and nowhere are you setting `p_strFilePath` in the code provided.

Comment: I forgot to change here in my code sample but in my project path is correct i.e "@"C:\\Files\\Sample.xlsx" .

yes same path is working fine if we create new excel sheet but while updating it is giving an error.

Comment: Do you really have the path set as `@"c:\\files\\sample.xlsx`? With the "@" symbol the string is taken literally and you don't need to escape backslashes - change those double backslashes to single and see what happens (or remove the "@")